# ngx-bootstrap/tabs 3.1.1 give StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabHeadingDirective -> TabDirective] in inner module

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

i'm trying to use the ngx-bootstrap / tabs component in a inner module inside an angular 6 project, but i've got this error in console, and the rendering crash:

```
   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabHeadingDirective -> TabDirective]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabHeadingDirective -> TabDirective]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TabDirective!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabHeadingDirective -> TabDirective]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabHeadingDirective -> TabDirective]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TabDirective!
...
```

If i import this component in the app.module.ts everything works fine, when i try to use it in a sub-module ( called shared ) i get the error at the top.
the config file for the module (shared.module.ts) looks like below:

```
...
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
...
TabsModule,
...
],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I have no idea how to solve it, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You must verify that there are no variables or properties named like in the TabModule.

My case was:

I have a custom compoentent with a property `@Input() tab: string = '0';` parameter to select a tab in the tabset.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabDirective -> TabsetComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabDirective -> TabsetComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TabsetComponent!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:691) ...
```

this is my custom component:

```
<my-component [datos]="datos" [tab]="tab"></my-component>
```

Then I changed the name `tab` for `tabID`

```
<my-component [datos]="datos" [tabId]="tabId"></my-component>
```

And `@Input() tabId: string = '0';`

I also change de `TabModule` of `ngx-bootstrap` for `NgbModule` of `ng-bootstrap`

That solve for me. What's your issue?

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it thanks to your response. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in the end of the import module .forRoot() like so : `TabsModule.forRoot()`

**UPDATE**

You need to import SharedModule to your root module aswell, e.g. *AppModule*

Comment: I've tryed also to do that, but does not work,it gives me same error. Seams to be somethink related to the provider for TabDirective. Maybe i should declare some provider to the component i'm using the Tabs component...

Comment: can you update question how you are trying to use it in a component and how the NgModule looks like dince you have it stripped down currently in your question. Im suspecting you are not wrapping things correctly in a <tabset>

Comment: I just noticed the name of module, have you imported SharedModule into your root module, e.g. "AppModule"? Are you lazy-loading anything in the app?

Comment: Starting Angular 6 dependency injection behaves differently, simplest way is to import Tabs forRoot() module into module where you are planning to use it

Comment: Same problem - Except with BsDropdownModule... (other non valor modules work...)